# Prove that $\langle \{(123…n),(12) \} \rangle =S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I know that $\langle \{(123…n),(12) \}\rangle  \subset S_n$. I was thinking that if I could show that $\langle \{(123…n),(12)\} \rangle $ contains all the transpositions of $S_n$ then it would contain $S_n$. How would I go about showing this?

Comment: All you need is that the subgroup contains all transpositions of the form $(k\,k+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can first prove that $S_n$ is generated by $(k\;\;\;k+1)$ for $k=1,2,\ldots,n-1$.  Then, check that
$$(1\;2\;3\;\ldots\;n)^{k-1}(1\;2)(1\;2\;3\;\ldots\;n)^{-(k-1)}=(k\;\;\;k+1).$$

Comment: It should be exponent $k-1$.

Comment: @Berci Edited, thanks!